# Convert Special Characters (other language) to English in PHP

Tags: php, character

Is there a function that coverts special characters to their english equivalents. For Eg. Convert é to e. Etc...

Answer (score 6):

The function you are after is [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) - from the user notes, this seems to be what you want to do: [characters transliteration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#94946)

Comment: When I used iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str); to convert João, it returened Joo

I would like it to return Joao...

Comment: Make sure the string is truly UTF-8. Encoding could be why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Isn't there a script that changes everything (all type of formattings) to plain english. I can't get the code to work :(

Comment: `echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', "Jo\xc3\xa3o");` Note that I've hard coded the 'ã' as UTF-8 (0xc3a3) to ensure that the encoding is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You should use this one and it will works:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'nl_BE.utf8');
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

I've tested it a lot of accentuated characters

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like danp's solution (iconv), you could use `strtr` with a list of conversions. [This page](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2004/05/17/convert-accented-characters-to-their-non-accented-equivalents-in-php/) has a sample script (first Google result).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function holding a array of chars you want exchanged and pass strings through and just change ã to a that way, if iconv() doesn´t work out for you.